# Maximum a posterior estimation and learning

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I have been thinking about binary state model, and I am trying to link it to MAP (maximum a posterior) estimator.

Suppose there is a binary state $\theta=\{L,H\}$, and my prior is $p_{0}\in (0,1) $. I believe that the state is $H$ with probability $p_{0}$.

The true state is unobservable, but there is an informative signal. If the state is $j \in \{H,L\}$, a (binary) signal $s_{j}$ occurs with probability $q_{j}>0.5$. After observing the first signal, my prior will be updated to $p_{1}$ according to the Bayes’ rule.

Now I want to augment(?) the state space to $\theta_{mixed}= \alpha L + (1-\alpha)H$ where $\alpha \in (0,1)$. As this is continuous-state, I know this is a very different problem, and I have a prior distribution.

However, I want to focus only on the mode of distribution.

My question is:

Given the mode of prior distribution of $\alpha$ as $p_{0}$, does $p_{1}$ correspond to the mode of posterior of the distribution? (MAP estimator after the first observation).

Comment: Could you give us more details and explain the symbols you’re using?

Comment: For instance—prior belief in _what_? In the initial observation being $L$? Are $L$ and $H$ real numbers? Otherwise, how can you take a convex combination of them?

Comment: I am sorry for confusions. I edited a bit. I was trying to say that there is a continuous space.